# @Unique doesn't have any effect in DataNucleus w/ NeoDatis

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus, object-oriented-database

Using JDO / DataNucleus / NeoDatis datastore

I added @Unique to a field of a persistable object, however I am allowed to create multiple objects which violate the unique constraint. The docs for DataNucleus/NeoDatis suggest that Unique fields are supported.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User {
 @Persistent
 @Unique
 private String username;
 //...
}
```

If I add multiple objects to the DB with the same username there's no problem doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the DataNucleus implementation for NeoDatis doesn't support unique attributes. In NeoDatis it requires that you add a unique index on the field (see link below for NeoDatis forums describing this).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/neodatis-odb/forums/forum/619814/topic/3409305

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify a name for your [unique constraint](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jdo/annotations.html#Unique) ?

```
@Unique(name="USERNAME_IDX")
private String username;
```

Comment: No difference if I give it a name. I can still add two objects with the same attribute string 'username'